# NEAR protocol near-js-api documentation on how to use the API

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm working on a web app and want to have a login with near button to connect to the network through the web wallet, so my user can call contracts in the network. I have found the corgi example app hosted on https://corgis.near.org/, and this code looks like it is connecting to the web wallet: https://github.com/nearprotocol/corgis/blob/master/src/index.js#L13

```
async function InitContract() {
  const nearConfig = getConfig(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development");

  // Initializing connection to the NEAR
  const near = await nearlib.connect({
    deps: {
      keyStore: new nearlib.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore(),
    },
    ...nearConfig,
  });

  // Needed to access wallet
  const walletConnection = new nearlib.WalletConnection(near);

  // Load in account data
  let currentUser;
  if (walletConnection.getAccountId()) {
    currentUser = {
      accountId: walletConnection.getAccountId(),
      balance: (await walletConnection.account().state()).amount,
    };
  }
```

but I'm trying to find some documentation for the https://github.com/near/near-api-js library which provides a bit more insights on how things work, what are the options for example to connect to different networks (betanet, testnet, mainnet).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the documentation for the near-api-js: https://near.github.io/near-api-js/ which explains how to provide a chainId to the network which you want to connect: https://near.github.io/near-api-js/interfaces/_utils_network_.network.html.